# Append to div without replacing the content, just adding to the end

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following div:

```
<div id="flip" class="container">
    <div class="f-page f-cover">
        <div class="cover-elements">
            <div class="f-cover-story">
                <span>Life Events</span>
                Photo Album
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="f-cover-flip">
            &lt; swipe
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And i am trying to add to this div like this:

```
for(var i = events.length; i > 0 ; i -= 5 ){
                    result_html += "<div class='f-page'>";
                        result_html += "<div class='f-title'>";
                            result_html += "<a href='index.jsp'>Back to bookshelf</a>";
                            result_html += "<h2 id='event_name'>Your Life Events</h2>";
                            result_html += "<a href='#'></a>";
                        result_html += "</div>";

                        if(index < events.length){
                            result_html += "<div class='box w-25 h-70' id='top_left_box'><div class='img-cont img-1'></div><h3>"
                                        + events[index].name + "<span>Published " + "From: " + events[index].start_date + "to: " + events[index].end_date + "</span></h3><p>"
                                        + events[index].description + " With: " + events[index].participants[0].name + "<img src="+events[index].participants[0].pictureUrl + " /></p></div>";

                            index++;
                        }
                        if(index < events.length){

                            result_html += "<div class='box w-50 h-70 box-b-l box-b-r' id='top_center_box'><div class='img-cont img-2'></div><h3>"
                                        + events[index].name + "<span>Published " + "From: " + events[index].start_date + "to: " + events[index].end_date + "</span></h3><p>"
                                        + events[index].description + " With: " + events[index].participants[0].name + "<img src="+events[index].participants[0].pictureUrl + " /> </p></div>";
                            index++;
                        }   
                        if(index < events.length){

                            result_html += "<div class='box w-25 h-70' id='top_right_box'><div class='img-cont img-3'></div><h3>"
                                        + events[index].name + "<span>Published " + "From: " + events[index].start_date + "to: " + events[index].end_date + "</span></h3><p>"
                                        + events[index].description + " With: " + events[index].participants[0].name + "<img src="+events[index].participants[0].pictureUrl + " /></p></div>";

                            index++;
                        }
                        if(index < events.length){
                            result_html += "<div class='box w-50 h-30 box-b-r title-top' id='bottom_left_box'><h3>"
                                        + events[index].name + "<span>Published " + "From: " + events[index].start_date + "to: " + events[index].end_date + "</span></h3><p>"
                                        + events[index].description + " With: " + events[index].participants[0].name + "<img src="+events[index].participants[0].pictureUrl + " /></p></div>";
                            index++;
                        }
                        if(index < events.length){
                            result_html += "<div class='box w-50 h-30 title-top' id='bottom_right_box'><h3>" 
                                        + events[index].name + "<span>Published " + "From: " + events[index].start_date + "to: " + events[index].end_date + "</span></h3><p>"
                                        + events[index].description + " With: " + events[index].participants[0].name + "<img src="+events[index].participants[0].pictureUrl + " /></p></div>";
                            alert("<img src="+events[index].participants[0].pictureUrl + " />");
                            index++;
                        }
                    result_html += '</div>';

                }

                result_html += "<div class='f-page f-cover-back'><div id='codrops-ad-wrapper'><a href='index.jsp' >Back to bookshelf</a></div></div>";

                $(".container").append(result_html);

                alert($(".container").html());

            });
```

What is happening is that it appends but the div that was there

```
<div class="f-page f-cover">
            <div class="cover-elements">
                <div class="f-cover-story">
                    <span>Life Events</span>
                    Photo Album
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="f-cover-flip">
                &lt; swipe
            </div>
        </div>
```

appears has blank when i make the `alert($(".container").html());`

from what i saw in the jquery append function this should work but it seems as if it is replancing or deleting the content of the flip div. why?

**EDIT**

This is happening because i am doing the alert inside a ajaxStop jquery.

If i do this inside document.ready it returns the content. Why is this happening?

Comment: could you provide `events` json?

Comment: To start with, there's a syntax error on the last line of the JS code you provided. In `});`, the close paren is unnecessary. Should be just `};`.

Comment: ReferenceError: events is not defined

Comment: Events is defined and when i add the div i have hardcoded to the for loop it prints it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can probably try

```
$(result_html).appendTo($('.container'));
```

instead of

```
 $(".container").append(result_html);
```

For me it works.